# javascript bitwise operator question

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

In Javascript when I do this

```
var num = 1;

~ num == -2
```

**why does ~num not equal 0**

> in binary 1 is stored as 1 ... thus not 1 should be 0
>
> *or it is stored like 0001 thus not 0001 would be 1110*
>
> I think I am missing something... can someone clear this up

Comment: You forgot about _all_ the other bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look up [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for signed binary numbers

Lets assume that a javascript Number is 8 bits wide (which its not):

then

```
1 = 0000 0001b
```

and

```
~1 = 1111 1110b
```

Which is the binary representation of `-2`

```
0000 0010b =  2
0000 0001b =  1
0000 0000b =  0
1111 1111b = -1
1111 1110b = -2
```

Answer (score 2):

`~` toggles the bits of the operand so

```
00000001
```

becomes

```
11111110
```

which is -2

Note: In javascript, the numbers are 32-bit, but I shortened it to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

> Bitwise NOTing any number x yields -(x + 1). For example, ~5 yields -6.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that using a bitwise NOT reverses all the bits of a value. If you are storing the value of 1 in a signed 8-bit integer, you're storing the binary value 00000001. If you apply a bitwise NOT, you get 11111110, which for a signed 8-bit integer is the binary value for -2.