# What is operator ~ for?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript bitwise operator question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261652/javascript-bitwise-operator-question)

Documentation says, that it is `bitwise NOT`. But I don't understand these examples:

```
var a = ~1; a
-2
var a = ~8; a
-9
var a = ~-1; a
0
```

Comment: Yes, it is bitwise NOT. Did you then go onto the internet to find out what bitwise NOT is?

Comment: please provide a link to where you got this code from?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, if I ask this question, then I have troubles with understanding, even after looking for information.

Comment: Your question is more language agnostic and should be "What is bitwise NOT"?

Comment: You might as well ask what the addition operator does-- This isn't a constructive question, it's a well documented concept that exists in hundreds of languages.

Comment: @DotNET Ninja: Are you sure, is this the complete example? I wonder something is missing from your example.