# ~ bitwise operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I have the following code :

```
var a = parseInt('010001',2);
console.log(a.toString(2));
//  10001
var b = ~a;
console.log(b.toString(2));
// -10010
```

[The MSDN Say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

> ~ Performs the NOT operator on each bit. NOT a yields the inverted
>   value (a.k.a. one's complement) of a.

**010001** should thus return this **101110**.

[This Topic kinda confirm that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261652/javascript-bitwise-operator-question)

So I can't understand how we can get **-10010** instead ? The only potential explanation is that:

> 010001 is negated 101110 but he write this -10001
>   and then for an obscure reason he give me the two complements
>   and -10001 become -10010.

But all this is very obscure in my mind, would you have an idea on what happen precisely.

Comment: It looks like Javascript considers this to be a 32-bit signed int under the covers. 0b010001 = 0x00000011, or decimal 17. The one's complement of this is 0xFFFFFFEE, or decimal -18, when treated as a signed 32-bit int, which equates to 0x11111111,11111111,11111111,11101110.

Comment: Also, 0b10010 is positive 18, so -0b10010 is -18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the covers, when Javascript does bitwise operations, it converts to a 32-bit signed integer representation, and uses that, then converts the result back into its internal decimal representation.

As such, your input value, `010001` becomes `00000000 00000000 00000000 00010001`.

This is then inverted:

```
~00000000 00000000 00000000 00010001 => 11111111 11111111 11111111 11101110
```

Converted into hex, the inverted value is `0xFFFFFFEE`, which is equivalent to the decimal value of -18.

Since this is a **signed integer** with a value of -18, this value is converted to the underlying **decimal** representation of -18 by Javascript.

When Javascript tries to print it as a base-2 number, it sees the negative sign and the value of 18, and prints it as `-10010`, since `10010` is the binary representation of positive 18.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shotgun Ninja. i Think it does explain what was confusing me ... my binary skills are rusted ! :)

Comment: i add this very cool link to understand 2's complement conversion http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-a-Negative-Binary-to-Decimal

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript's bitwise operators convert their operands to 32-bit signed integers (the usual [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)), perform their operation, then return the result as the most appropriate value in JavaScript's number type (double-precision floating point; JavaScript doesn't have an integer type). More in [§12.5.11 (Bitwise NOT Operator `~`)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-bitwise-not-operator) and [§7.1.5 (`ToInt32`)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toint32).

So your `10001` is:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00010001
```

which when `~` is:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11101110
```

...which is indeed negative in 2s complement representation.

You may be wondering: If the bit pattern is as above, then why did `b.toString(2)` give you `-10010` instead? Because it's showing you signed binary, not the actual bit pattern. `-` meaning negative, and `10010` meaning 18 decimal. The bit pattern above is how that's represented in 2s complement bits. (And yes, I *did* have to go check myself on that!)

Comment: But that isn't -18 is it?

Comment: @musefan: Turns out I don't have my bits wrong. `11111111 11111111 11111111 11101110` in 2s complement binary is -18 decimal.

Comment: I thought negatives where just identify by the first bit, but Im too tired to think about this properly so see y'all Monday!

Comment: @musefan: That would be in the bit pattern, yes, but not JavaScript's `toString(2)` output, which outputs a binary number with a number sign. Confusing, I know, I had to go double-check.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer T.J Crowder i think i lack understanding on how 2s complement work ...

Comment: Two's complement can be pretty confusing at first and is not very intuitive imo. The wikipedia page explaines it pretty well, but it takes some time (and a clear head) to work through it ;)

Comment: @seb_kaine: I'm told 2s complement is quite simple, but I tend to struggle with it as well (as you can tell from the editing history above!). :-) Basically, if you have a four-bit number `1100` (the high-order bit being 1 means it's negative) and you subtract that from the number with one more bit (`10000`), and called it negative, you'd have the value in question. The WP article above helps explain it.

Comment: @T.J Crowder Thanks for precision ! :)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript uses 32-bit signed numbers,so

```
a (010001) (17) is  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0001
b = ~a (?) (-18) is 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1110
```

The reason for printing -18 as -10010 and methods to get actual value is explained well here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24153275/2824131)

Comment: Thanks for the extra precision AcidBurn !

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation on the Mozilla developer website [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT). Bitwise NOTing any number x yields -(x + 1). For example, ~5 yields -6. That is why you are getting the negative sign in front of the number.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes as this explain the problem perfectly

Comment: This covers up the details of what's actually happening, but it's a nice rule of thumb to remember. If the OP is using bitwise operations, it's probably more correct to explain how they work than it is to provide an answer which glosses over them for sake of simplicity.

Comment: This doesn't explain _why_, see T.J. Crowder's answer for a better explanation.

Comment: It's not wrong, just it doesn't explain the problem. It just sais the result is to be expected, however without explaining why. Though it doesn't deserve the downvotes imo

Comment: Thanks for your Help Rahul

Comment: Or perhaps more obviously, because `-x = ~x + 1` (by definition), `-x - 1 = ~x` (subtract one on both sides), which is obviously also `-(x + 1)`