# In javascript, whether Bitwise OR use iee-754 as storage format during calculation nor not ？

Tags: javascript, ieee-754, bitwise-or

if Bitwise OR was used ieee-754 to calc the result in Javascript,i can't understand the result.

for example:

```
2|1 =>3
```

In ieee-754,
`2` is stored as `0 10000000000 0000...0000`,and
`1` is stored as `0 01111111111 0000...0000`

if exec bitwise or,i think the result is `0 11111111111 0000...0000`,but why does it output `3`?

As same as above,

example:

```
0.1|0 =>0
```

`0` is stored as `0 00000000000 0000...0000`,and 
`0.1` is stored as `0 01111111011 1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010`

if exec bitwise or,i think the result is `0 01111111011 1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010`,but why does it output `0`,and lose decimal?

example:

```
2|-1 =>-1
```

`2` is stored as `0 10000000000 0000...0000`,and
`-1` is stored as `1 01111111111 0000...0000`

if exec bitwise or,i think the result is `1 11111111111 0000...0000`,but why does it output `-1`?

Comment: in javascript the number is converted to a 32 bit integer number, then the bitwise operation is made and the result is converted back to the standard format of 64 bit float..

Comment: Have some spec or document indicate that ? @NinaScholz

Comment: here you go: [Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Comment: [How do I convert a float number to a whole number in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/a/12837315)  Also [Read/Write bytes of float in JS](//stackoverflow.com/a/35748581) for actually type-punning so you could bitwise OR the bit-patterns of floating-point numbers.  Not exactly a duplicate, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [~ bitwise operator in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527807/bitwise-operator-in-javascript) (The answers there state that bitwise operators convert from `Number` (double) to 32 bit integer)

Comment: but why 0.1|0 is output 0? As the document,number will convert to 32bit,but after bitwise or,the result should be `0 01111011 10011001100110011001101`

Comment: you miss the integer part.

Comment: 1.1|0 is output 1,also lose the decimal,i wonder that why the decimal was lost@NinaScholz.if javascript lose decimal in 32-bit,not use ieee-754 binary32

Comment: @HanQ again, bitwise operations first convert the number to a 32 bit ***integer*** so `0.1` would be converted into `0b0` while `1.1` would be converted to `0b1` before the operation is even calculated.

Comment: what is mean `0b0`?what's the `b`?@VLAZ

Comment: `0b` - prefix meaning "binary number" `0b0` - zero in binary, `0b10` is the binary number for the decimal `2`.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is an implementation of ECMAScript. The [ECMAScript 2018 Language Specification (9th edition, June 2018)](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) specifies the binary bitwise operators in clause 12.12. The evaluation steps in 12.12.3 include (using “@” to stand for one of the bitwise operations):

5. Let lnum be ? ToInt32(lval).
6. Let rnum be ? ToInt32(rval).
7. Return the result of applying the bitwise operator @ to lnum and rnum. The result is a signed 32-bit integer.

Thus, the bitwise operation is not performed on the bytes that represent a `Number`. The value of the `Number` is converted to a 32-bit two’s complement representation of an integer, and the operation is performed on those bits. Then resulting bits are then interpreted as a 32-bit two’s complement representation, so the value they represent becomes the value produced by the operation.